# SSH error : name or service not known

Tags: ruby, ssh

I am getting this error because, there are 5 peripheral trays on 10 available slots(subjected to change at anytime) so i have no other option other than pinging all of them and performing a command(killall). Is there a way to disable viewing this error and just performing the operation if the tray is available and ignore other wise

PS: am writing ruby script
help me out

code goes like this
for i loop
 ssh -f -n user@host_$i      killall -9 process

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are you SSHing into?

Comment: @blueberryfields
code goes like this
 for i loop 
ssh -f -n user@host_$i killall -9 process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Curious if this block solves the problem, not a great solution , but tried to refine on the exception one ...

```
killports = 0
killedcount=false
if (killedcount===false)
  while killports <= 10
begin
  puts killports
  killports=killports+1
  killedcount=true
  ssh -f -n user@host_$i killall -9 process    rescue Exception =>e
  puts "Comming to an exception"
  if killports<=10 && killedcount===true then
    killedcount=false
    retry
  else
    raise
  end
end
killedcount=false
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Will this be a workable solution?? Added your code into a Exception handling block and not doing anything in the handle.

```
for i loop
Begin 
    ssh -f -n user@host_$i killall -9 process
Ensure Exception =>e
   //Forget about logging anything
End
```

Comment: won't exceptions cause the loop to stop running?